# decomposing a factor group into a direct sum of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n ^*$ be the set of all units in $\mathbb{Z}_n$  and $(\mathbb{Z}_n ^*)^2$ = $\{ a^2 | a \in \mathbb{Z}_n ^*\} $

Then,  decompose the factor group  $\mathbb{Z}_n ^* / (\mathbb{Z}_n ^*)^2$

1.when $n$ is an odd prime

2.when $n$ is a product of two distinct odd primes $p, q$

I solved the first as following: In $\mathbb{Z}_p$, since $x^2=(p-x)^2$ holds, the order of $(\mathbb{Z}_n ^*)^2$ is exactly the half of that of $\mathbb{Z}_n ^*$.

Thus, the answer is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

However the second is more complicated. I didn't know that. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

With your notation:

$$\Bbb Z_{pq}^*=\Bbb Z^*_p\times\Bbb Z^*_q$$

The above's based on the well known property of Euler's Totient Function

$$\phi(pq)=\phi(p)\phi(q)=(p-1)(q-1)$$

Comment: I know that both groups have the same order. However, since both p-1 and q-1 may not be prime, may your hint be incorrect?  For example, if p=3, q=5, the group in the left has order 8, which is the order of $\mathbb{Z}_8$, different from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ X $\mathbb{Z}_4 $,

Comment: The group $\;\Bbb Z_{15}^*\;$ is **not** cyclic...!

Comment: Oh I checked that they are isonorphic. You are right. Then is the answer of  the second problem is the klein 4group because $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^*$ is not cyclic?

Comment: How can that be the Klein group if $\;p,q\;$ *different odd* primes??

Comment: Um.. I applied the argument in my question, so I thought  the order of $(\Bbb Z^*_p\times\Bbb Z^*_q)^2$ is the 1/4 times of that of $\Bbb Z^*_p\times\Bbb Z^*_q$

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, now I see that you meant to ask whether *the quotient group* is the Klein group, not that direct product. Anyway, why don't you check it directly? For one, the Klein group **must** have more than one involution...

Comment: When I consider the case p=3 q=5, I think the answer is the klein group...

Comment: And what about *other* cases? Say, $\;p=2\,,\,q=7\;$ ...?

Comment: My question covers only two odd primes..

Comment: Well, then take $\;p=3\;$...

Comment: It has the same result...

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^\ast = \mathbb{Z}_p^\ast \times \mathbb{Z}_q^\ast$, and $(\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^\ast)^2 = (\mathbb{Z}_p^\ast)^2 \times (\mathbb{Z}_q^\ast)^2$.

Comment: Hence is the answer is klein group?

Comment: @JeongNam-ho That should be easy enough to check, no?

Comment: What are you saying..?T.T. So, Is it the klein group??

Comment: @JeongNam-ho Well, what is the answer for $n=15$?  How would a confident mathematician ask this question?

Comment: I think, the answer is the klein group for the case n=15.....